# How to make vaadin combo box label always floating

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin, polymer-1.0

I am working with polymer vaadin combo box in java gwt. But the label is always shown in-line . How to make it always floating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the code for setting the attributes

`paperContainerElement.setAttribute("always-float-label", "true");`

and the code will go like this

```
           box.ready(new Function() {

            @Override
            public Object call(Object arg) {

            NodeList<Node> children =box.getElement().getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = children.getItem(i);                      
            if (node.getNodeName().equals("PAPER-INPUT-CONTAINER")) {
            Element paperContainerElement = (Element) node;
            paperContainerElement.setAttribute("always-float-label", "true");
            break;                
                                  }               
                              }

            return null;
            }

        });
```

The above code is simply to force inherit the `alwaysFloatLabel` from the outer `vaadinComboBox` to the paperInputContainer inside it.

Comment: Thanks ... that helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

For html you can add always-float-label parameter as true

Example:

```html
<vaadin-combo-box
          label="Mode"
          always-float-label="true"
          class="otherField"
          items='["Normal","Shuffle"]'
          value="{{modeString}}"
>
</vaadin-combo-box>
```